# WPF Docking library error?

Tags: wpf

I use DockingLibrary :
 http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFdockinglib.aspx
but when I want to dock dockablecontent in the center(just in the center) of dockmanager an error raise:
object reference not set to an instance of an object 
note: I use VS2010. 
what can I do to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer your actual question, but have you thought about using AvalonDock? AvalonDock is a newer version of the WPF Docking Library that you linked to.

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

and [Sofa](http://sofawpf.codeplex.com), its wrapper.